# Java GUI won't display JLabel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, frame

I would like to create a simple GUI in Java. I know the basics of creating `JLabel`, etc. However, I cannot find why my `JLabel` is not displayed on the screen. Here is my code:

```
package test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class A1Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener { 
    JLabel firstInt;

    public void init() {
        makeComponents();
        makeLayout();
    }

    private void makeComponents() {
        firstInt = new JLabel("First argument");
        firstInt.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 16));
        firstInt.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        firstInt.setVisible(true);
        firstInt.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    }

    private void makeLayout() {
        add(firstInt);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    }
}
```

I then add my `JPanel` to my `JFrame` using a different class called GUI:

```
import test.A1Panel;

public class GUI {
public static void main(String[] args) {       
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing GUI"); 
    frame.setLayout( new GridLayout(1,3));

    JPanel panel = new A1Panel();
    panel.setBorder( BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder() );
    frame.add( panel);

    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.pack();
    }
}
```

When I hit compile, what I get is a simple frame with three *empty* panels. I do not understand why my `JLabel` is not in the first panel since I have added it to my frame. Am I missing something?

Comment: Call Swing-related code on the EDT thread, not on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

After you instance A1Panel, you haven't called `A1Panel.init()`

I would suggest removing `init()` and adding all the code to the constructor of `A1Panel`. If, however, you wanted to keep the `init()` function, you would want to call it after `JPanel panel = new A1Panel()`

Comment: Where should I call it then?

Comment: @fireshadow52, incorrect. If he were to call `panel.init()` it would work, without the need for a `static` modifier.

Answer (score 2):

The frame is not empty, the panel is. Nowhere in your code do I see a call to the methods `init()` or `makeComponents()`. In fact, I would turn your `init()` method into a constructor, like so:

```
public A1Panel() {
    makeComponents();
    makeLayout();
}
```

Another alternative to this would be to call `panel.init()` after declaring `JPanel panel = new A1Panel()`

Answer (score 1):

The code to add the label was not actually called in the main, was it? So look carefully, when is init actually called?

Look at the

```
private void makeLayout()
```

method.

Answer (score 1):

If I replace `public void init()` by `A1Panel()`, it does the job. Thank you for your help.